# How can I add checkbox in v-card in vuetiy

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I want to add selectable checkbox in card which selects the card value, somewhat like the image below

[image]

But, when I code the result is not satisfying.

```html
<v-container class="py-0">
  <v-row
    align="center"
    justify="start"
  >
    <v-col
      v-for="(address, i) in addresses"
      :key="i"
      cols="12"
    >
      <v-card
        class="mx-auto"
        v-if="addresses!=null"
        elevation="10"
      >
      <v-col cols="2">
        <v-checkbox v-model="disabled" class="mx-2"></v-checkbox>
      </v-col>
      <v-col cols="10">
        <v-card-title class="headline">{{ address.tag }}</v-card-title>
        <v-card-subtitle>{{ address.flatNo }}, {{ address.landmark }}, {{ address.area }}<br>{{address.pincode}}
        </v-card-subtitle>
      </v-col>                    
     </v-card>
    </v-col>
  </v-row>
</v-container>
```

It gives result like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<v-card>
  <v-list-item two-line>
    <v-list-item-action>
      <v-checkbox />
    </v-list-item-action>
    <v-list-item-content>
      <v-list-item-title class="headline mb-1">{{ address.tag }}</v-list-item-title>
      <v-list-item-subtitle>{{ address.flatNo }}, {{ address.landmark }}, {{ address.area }}{{address.pincode}}</v-list-item-subtitle>
    </v-list-item-content>
  </v-list-item>
  <v-card-text>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Maiores, amet laudantium! Eveniet beatae corrupti assumenda expedita consequuntur itaque, similique debitis rem laudantium hic voluptates aliquam quam eligendi nulla ipsum quidem.
  </v-card-text>
</v-card>
```

This answer is based on vuetify documentation https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/cards/#outlined-cards

Result: https://codepen.io/yozhis/pen/ZEGdZEv